# Spring Boot + JPA (Hibernate) - how to update some fields

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have to update my entity - when `placeA` or/and `placeB` is updated, I have to also update `points`.
SO I fetch route object from database and modify one or two fields (`placeA`, `placeB`). The problem is that I have to update `points` accordingly -> in `Point` object I have to also update `pointAddress` (`point.pointAddress` has to be updated to `route.placeA` or `route.placeB` values):

```
public class Route{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "place_a_id")
    private Address placeA;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "place_b_id")
    private Address placeB;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "route", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Point> points;
```

```
public class Point{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "point", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<PointDetail> pointDetails;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "route_id", nullable = false)
    private Route route;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "route_address_id", nullable = false)
    private Address pointAddress;
```

```
public class PointDetail{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "point_id", nullable = false)
    private Point point;
```

And I fetch `Route` entity from db and from now this object is in persistent state (everything within the same transaction) so I don't need to invoke `repository.save(myChangedRoute)` explicitly.

The question is how to update `route.points[0].pointAddress`?

Is it sufficient?

```
Route route = repository.findRouteById(1L);
route.setPointA("new place");
route.getPoints().get(0).setPointAddress("new place")
```

And what with `route.getPoints().get(0).getRoute()` and `route.getPoints().get(0).getPointDetails()` objects? For example should I also update `route.getPoints().get(0).getPointDetails()` object? `PointDetail` objects have a field `point` that maybe should be also updated?

I have related (nested) objects in my Route object (dependencies) so my question is how to update my object structure properly to not overwrite new values with the old nested ones that are not updated, e.g. I updated:
`route.getPoints().get(0).setPointAddress("new place")`

but I haven't updated `route.getPoints().get(0).getPointDetails().get(0).setPoint(MY NEW UPDATED AND NOT YET SAVED Point object)`???

SO we have a circular dependencies `route -> point -> pointDetail -> point` and the question is if it's sufficient to update only `pointAddress` in my `route.point` object or I have to also update `pointAddress` in `route.point.pointDetail.point`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: `point -> pointDetail -> point` is not a curricular dependecny. The relation between pointDetail and point is BiDirectional dependency.

*PointDetail objects have a field point that maybe should be also updated?* Of course not.

*and the question is if it's sufficient to update only pointAddress in my route.point?* Yes that is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate has the first level cache it ensures that objects will be loaded only once per session. So no override can occur. Of course, is up to you and your code how will you update properties and in which order.